# Beermapping API Jquery parse

Tags: jquery, xml

So I am trying to use jquery to parse xml from a url and for some reason I am not getting any results inside the div that I am appending to. I'm currently stuck and would appreciate any help. Thanks

Here is what my jquery file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://beermapping.com/webservice/locquery/3e16c831988820466c88ab11ed02a47c/rochester',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: "xml",
success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
 $(xml).find('location').each(function() {  
      $("#left").append($(this).find("location").text());
  });
 }
```

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from ajaxing content from other origins(domains, ports, protocol). Since that site doesn't seem to provide [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers you'll have to make a server side proxy to get the information.